# How to reduce the Page load time of angular-meteor based web application in mobile?

Tags: angularjs, performance, meteor, angular-ui-router, angular-meteor

I'm developing a web application using angular-meteor 1.x where accesses are almost always from smartphones. On average loading the css and js takes 3 seconds, but the application is only ready for use after 10 or 15 seconds depending on the smarphone. Is there any way to slow down this time?

1. I'm already using the cache
2. I read in the documentation that the components are loaded with lazy load
3. my application already has 16 components
4. on the login page after the download the download is around 450kb ~

Comment: Display a loading page until the app is ready?

Comment: I already do this, but I wanted a way to optimize.